# T-SQL com like sensitivo a maiúsculas e minúsculas

Tags: sql-server, tsql, operador-like, sensibilidade-de-caixa

É possível fazer uma consulta no SQL Server 2008 com like sensitivo? Na verdade, estou buscando em uma coluna com uma lista de acrônimos, que representam flags do sistema, que diferenciam maiúsculas e minúsculas.

A questão não se trata de performance dessa busca, pois sempre haverá um outro campo indexado sendo filtrado na mesma query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim é possível, mas antes é necessário saber qual o tipo de COLLATION que está configurado o seu SQL SERVER.
Para isso Verifique com a seguinte Select:

```
select databasepropertyex('databasename', 'collation') sqlcollation;
```

Se você tiver um resultado como:

```
sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as
```

Significa que Banco não diferencia Maiúsculas de Minúsculas e diferencia acentos;

Você pode:

- Mudar o agrupamento padrão do SQL Server para um novo
- Alterar o agrupamento do banco de dados, mas não aconselho, pois, além de não ser fácil, você provavelmente terá que migrar de um banco de dados antigo para um novo
- Criar colunas usando um agrupamento diferente do padrão Alterar o agrupamento diretamente (a mesma sintaxe é usada para criar colunas com diferentes agrupamentos)

  ```
  select coluna1 collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as as coluna1 from tabela1
  ```

Acho que é o melhor caminho a seguir, a não ser que seu banco de dados seja realmente muito grande e muito, muito confuso, é criar um novo banco de dados com o agrupamento correto.

Existem algumas maneiras de fazer isso , mas eu prefiro o meu script de banco de dados antigo e usar esse script para criar um novo com o agrupamento direito , depois migrar todas as informações selecionando o banco de dados antigo e inserir no novo usando o agrupamento cláusula para o novo agrupamento nas colunas varchar (evitando o erro de agrupamento inválido ) .

A justificativa é simples : mudar um agrupamento de uma unica coluna para comparação de string é muito custoso.

Answer (score 0):

Testei aqui e funcionou (meu banco é SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = Insensitive)

O dado existente: Insert into nomes (nome) Select 'Rogério S. Ferreira'

As opções de busca:

- Select * from nomes where nome like 'Rog%'
- Select * from nomes where nome like 'ROG%'
- Select * from nomes where nome like 'rog%'

Por ser "insensitive" todas as buscas funcionam...
Mas se acrescentar isso: "Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS" (Sensitive) , somente a primeira funcionará, Assim:

- Select * from nomes where nome like 'Rog%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
- Select * from nomes where nome like 'ROG%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
- Select * from nomes where nome like 'rog%' Collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS